# FFmpeg: не изменять размер если картинка меньше

Tags: ffmpeg, gif

Здравствуйте,

```
ffmpeg -i "in.mp4" -vf scale=680:-2 "out.gif"
```

Скажите как сохранить исходные WxH когда гифка менее 680px?

Т.е добиться такого же эффекта:

```
gifsicle -O3 --resize-fit-width 680 -i in.gif > out.gif
convert in.gif -resize "680x>" out.gif
```

Если ни как, то как получить эффект зернистости c gifsicle как в ffmpeg. Такая gif-ка весит значительно меньше.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно. Почитать про выражения в фильтрах: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation и про сам фильтр [scale](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale-1)

В вашем случае, будет что-то вроде:

```
ffmpeg -i "in.mp4" -vf scale='min(680\,iw):-2' "out.gif"
```

Comment: [libx264 @ 0xa6e1200] width not divisible by 2 (499x500) Error while opening encoder for output stream 0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height  
`"scale='min(680\,trunc(iw/2)*2)':-2"`